# rxJava stop observable on unsubscribe

Tags: rx-java

I have cold an observable that produce a lot of items when subscribed on computation Scheduler and send to another o who do a heavier work on them.

The issue is I want to stop all the observable chain when I unsubscribe from it.

There is any operator for that? I tried to check if I have a susbcriber, but at this point most of my items have been emitted.

Comment: calling `subscriber.unsubscribe()` will unsubscribe the whole chain. Do you have a single chain? Can you show some code?

Comment: @DaveMoten, Yeap my first observable stop emitting items, but my (slow) `flatmap` function keep working on the items emitted before en `unsubscribe` is called.

Comment: @GuilhermeTorresCastro your threads will get interrupted on unsubscribe - checkh the interrup status while you're doing work and exit prematurely when it's set.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos I tested and the interrupted status did not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an observable that does the heavy work and can check the subscription:

```
obs //emits stuff fast
  .flatMap(x -> 
    Observable.create(
        sub -> {
          //frequently check subscription status
          while (!sub.isUnsubscribed()) {
            // do some work
            if (finished) break;
          }
          if (!sub.isUnsubscribed()) {
            sub.onNext(result);
            sub.onCompleted();
          }
        }))
      //ensure backpressure compliant
      .onBackpressureBuffer() 
    ).subscribe(subscriber);
```

Comment: I am felling stupid for not thinking about that. Thanks!